# Is there a way to resize the image height and width posted by django-CKeditor?

Tags: ckeditor, django-ckeditor

Edit: Noone is answering this problem it seems. I'm editing in the hopes for this to reach out to other peoples.

I'm using django 6.5.1 as of creating this project. I am unable to make the resize option remove. I want the upload image to get resized automatically in the html page as **100%** width and height.
My settings.py is:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'height': 90,
         'width': 700,
        # 'skin': 'moono',
        # # 'skin': 'office2013',
        # 'toolbar_Basic': [
        #     ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        # ],
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Youtube','Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['CodeSnippet']},
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},

        ],
        'toolbar': 'Custom',  # put selected toolbar config here
        'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        'height': 400,
        'width': '100%',
        'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            'devtools',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath',
            'codesnippet',
            
        ]),
    }
}
```

I have this script in post_form.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
```

Edit: the HTML code is:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
              <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:'F d, Y'}}</small>
              {% if object.author == user %}
            <div>
              <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
              <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
            </p>

            <h2 class="article-title"> {{ object.title }} </h2>
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="rounded blog-pics-list" alt="post_img">
            <p class="article-content">{{ object.content | safe }}</p>
        </div>
    </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

What I want to do it to resize the image uploaded to CKEditor to

```
width: 100%;
height : 100%;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use css targeting the img tags in your site. if you have a sample html output, i could help write out the solution for you.

Comment: uhm I'm guess you want a [screenshot?](https://imgur.com/a/vfebPkV)

Comment: anyone still here please answer my request

Comment: We need the actual html output, not a screenshot. We can't write code specifically for your project if you don't provide show any code from your project. In this case, the views of your django showing this image that is uploaded.

Comment: Oh okay so you want the actual codes. Well, i've edited teh post and added it. I hope this suffices